# Apache URL rewrite - Trying to mask the folder name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website located at `example.com/cmsFolder` which I want to move to `example.com/newFolder`. I can't manually move this as it completely breaks this stupid CMS.

So I'm trying to use `mod_rewrite` to mask the folder name and keep it looking nice.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cmsFolder/(.*)$ /newFolder/$1 [L]
```

That fails with a 404. How can I mask the folder name? :/

Answer (score 4):

Try this, It works for me while adding this rules to Apache's main configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/cmsFolder/(.*)$ /newFolder/$1 [L]
```

I think you forgot first slash before cmsFolder. If you want to look at mod_rewrite logs:

```
RewriteLog "_PATH_TO_YOUR_\rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

As Paolo comments log directives are not allowed in .htacces. Easy to understand why :-)

**Edit:**

Probably if you want to mask the request you will use [P] modifier (Proxy):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/cmsFolder/(.*)$ /newFolder/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Nice.  I had no idea that there was a "RewriteLog" directive.  This is certainly better than the guess and check method.

Comment: Note the log directives can only go in the .conf files, they're not allowed in .htaccess files.

Comment: Thanks, I never use .htaccess files because I'm just using Apache for personal purposes. I will modify my response with this info if you agree :-)

Comment: When mod_rewrite is used in a .htaccess file, the local path prefix is removed from the URL path before before testing the rules. And the local path prefix for the root directory is `/`. That means all patterns must be written without that path prefix. So tab’s pattern actually was correct.

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution may be just to symlink the newFolder to cmsFolder

```
ln -s cmsFolder/ newFolder
```

Or you can create a short [PHP script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) if you don't have shell access:

```
<?php symlink('cmsFolder','newFolder'); ?>
```

Comment: Nice solution. You need to place 'Options FollowSymLinks' at your Apache configuration. If not this solution won't work. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite requests to `/newFolder/…` internally to `/cmsFolder/…`, you need to go  the other way round:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^newFolder/(.*)$ /cmsFolder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subfolder/login
RewriteRule ^login/(.*)$ subfolder/login/$1 [L]
```