# How to alter Domain redirection in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter.I just need my url to be look like this http://example.com/ instead of http://example.com/myCodefolder/. My installtion structure is like "public_html/myCodefolder/" where could I change.

Comment: Are you using Apache as server? You need to provide some more details about your setup.

Comment: what do you want me to provide ?am using apache currently

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242726/apache-url-rewrite-trying-to-mask-the-folder-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

You just move all the files from `myCodefolder` to `public_html` folder.

Here you dont need the `myCodefolder`.

Change the `base_url()` as `http://example.com/`

**Method 2**

Create an `.htaccess` file in `myCodefolder` and put the code,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myCodefolder/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This may helps you

Comment: Hi vinod.Is there any alternative.cause I am maintaining many folders in the domain like webservices..etc

Comment: @krishna I edited the answer to put another method using htaccess file

Comment: And I have a query.How come 2nd method works??cause I am not going to the directory myCodefolder.And this htaccess code will be applied if am using like www.example.com/myCodefolder/ .I just need this thing to be work at www.example.com